# How is a Challenge implemented for a game networking protocol?

Tags: c#, networking, litenetlib

Working on an authoritative online game using LiteNetLib. I've been reading about [building a game network protocol](https://gafferongames.com/post/client_server_connection/) and I'm feeling stuck with the "challenge" implementation.

- The client requests a connection with the server.
- The server then returns some sort of challenge (that only the client should be able to solve?).
- The client returns the solution and the server allows the connection.

The first thing that I don't get is how to have a "pending" connection without accepting it to begin with. With LiteNetLib, this is how the server handles incoming connections:

```
listener.ConnectionRequestEvent += request =>
{
    if(server.ConnectedPeersCount < 10 /* max connections */)
        request.AcceptIfKey("SomeConnectionKey");
    else
        request.Reject();
};
```

From the looks of it, the server must decide whether to allow the client or not at this very instant. If I want to send or receive a challenge, I need to accept the connection first don't I? But that would defeat the point of the challenge implementation.

Is there a resource with an example of how this is done? The article doesn't really go into detail, and when I google things like "online game protocol challenge request packet" the results aren't quite related (almost as if the concept was coined by that article).

Comment: The challenge just needs to be any random, unpredictable value that an attacker couldn't realistically guess. The reason it's a "challenge" is because the server is sending that information to the client's IP and port, so if an attacker is using a spoofed IP, they won't receive the challenge packet from the server because it will go to whoever actually owns that IP address. It's the same as sending someone a verification email when they sign up for a website. You can sign up with someone else's email address trivially, but you won't be able to verify unless you can actually read their email.